# How do I use GetFeatureInfo to get attribute information in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, popup, getfeatureinfo

I want to create a popup window as this one http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html when I click on the feature.. I used the same code but its not working... the pop up is not coming up....

Here is my code:

```
        info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms', 
        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
        queryVisible: true,
        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                    "chicken", 
                    map.getLocalXY(event.xy),
                    null,
                    event.text,
                    null,
                    true
                ));
            }
        }
    });     
     function onPopupClose(evt) {
        var feature = this.feature;
            if (feature.layer) {
                selectControl.unselect(feature);
            } else { 
                this.destroy();
            }
        }
        function onFeatureSelect(evt) {
            feature = evt.feature;
            popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                "featurePopup",
                 feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
                  new OpenLayers.Size(100,100),
                  "<h2>"+feature.attributes.title + "</h2>" +
                  feature.attributes.description,
                  null, true, onPopupClose);
                  feature.popup = popup;
                  popup.feature = feature;
                  map.addPopup(popup, true);
        }
        function onFeatureUnselect(evt) {
            feature = evt.feature;
            if (feature.popup) {
                popup.feature = null;
                map.removePopup(feature.popup);
                feature.popup.destroy();
                feature.popup = null;
            }
        };
```

Comment: You should post some part of the code where you're getting the error messages, are you getting them btw? What do they say?

Comment: I am not getting any error.. the pop up window is just not coming up.. and nothing happens when I click the features.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Javascript can't send a cross domain request. Unless you are hosting on `http://demo.opengeo.org` you'll require a proxy to make an Ajax request.

Comment: Huh?A proxy? I dont know what that is... Even when I use http://demo.opengeo.org it doesn work.

Comment: Probably most common problem with OpenLayers. As Devdatta told, you need to set up proxy. There are plenty of explanations and examples, for example: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost

Comment: http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms is hosted by Boundless (http://boundlessgeo.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't work with geoserver, but mapserver, so no idea what is going wrong there, but if I use in my browser:

`http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms`

I get:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.
>         http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">
>         Could not determine geoserver request from http request org.geoserver.monitor.MonitorServletRequest@4e9c20bf

not sure if this is the normal behavior, though.

Hope this helps,